# How to select textbox and textarea containing portion of id simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, textarea

How can I select textbox and textarea containing portion of an id? For instance i would like to select both textbox and textarea only containing id 'div1'.

I tried below lines

```
$("input[id*='div1'][type='text']")
```

this gives me only textboxes.

```
$("input[id*='div1'][type='text'],textarea")
```

this gives me all textboxes and textareas(not containing div1 also)

```
 $("input[id*='div1'][type='text','textarea'")
```

For this line an error is thrown stating invalid syntax.

Can anyone please help me??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the syntax `$("input[id^='div']")`, which selects elements whose id attribute values start with "div". https://jsfiddle.net/queryj/Lus74pfn/

Comment: @Stack0verflow id containing parts works correctly only section of textbox and textarea doesnt

Comment: `$("[id*='div1']") ` why the need to specify tags? if you want to limit to TA+inps, use a comma and repeat the partial ID attrib part, or give them a common class.

Comment: @PM77-1 I already have filter to select visible elements in the same query. Will adding another filter affect that second filteration?

Comment: `$("input[id*='div1'][type='text'],textarea[id*='div1']")` and second filter will have effect

Comment: @dandavis its an existing app containing over 200 inputs. Don't want to modify markup